# .htaccess to remove a string within a URL

Tags: .htaccess, url

I am working on a website that uses DokuWiki and the website is called [MiscWiki](http://www.miscwiki.org).

Currently all of the URLs are structured this way

```
http://www.miscwiki.org/doku.php/something/something
```

I would like to use a .htaccess rewrite to remove the doku.php from the URL. I currently have this statement but it is not working.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/doku.php/?(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thank you for the help on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
AcceptPathInfo On
RewriteEngine On

## Uncomment next 2 lines only when you want to remove doku.php/ from old links
#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+doku\.php/(\S*) [NC]
#RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .+ doku.php/$0 [L]
```

Comment: This works well and answers the question, but it causes a problem I did not predict. Links on the site that have the old URL structure now do not work. Is there a way to make this work, whilst preserving old links that still contain doku.php?

Comment: On the homepage of miscwiki.org, the links in blue now no longer work and I think it is because they still contain doku.php.

Comment: ok I commented out first redirect rule. You can test after clearing browser cache.

Comment: Thank you for all the help, I will keep working on this problem and see if I can come to a solution. All the best